# Meta Box: display single image on an archive-template

Tags: categories, metabox, archives

I'm trying to get the url of an image from a MetaBox (plugin) filed on an archive-page.

```
<?php  
    if ( rwmb_meta( 'field-id' ) ) {

        // Get images   
        $img_srcset_large = rwmb_meta( 'field-id', array( 'size' => 'image-size', 'limit' => 1  ) ); 


        echo $img_srcset_large['url'] 
?>
```

Unfortunately there is nothing displayed.
Can you give me a hint how this code can work on archive-templates?
Best

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Could you post more of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = rwmb_meta( 'field-id', array( 'size' => 'image-size', 'limit' => 1  ) );
$image = reset( $images );

echo $image['url'];
```

[reference](https://docs.metabox.io/fields/image/)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit and explain why this is an answer?

Comment: are you sure that `field-id` is the actual id of your meta-box element ? it looks more like taken from an example. You've to match the id used in the rwmb initialization with: `array(
    'name'             => 'Image Upload',
    'id'               => 'field_id',
    'type'             => 'image'
`

Comment: Yes of cause, I just used a standard name to show you that. It still not doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

I just found out there need to be special term-id, so like this

```
$value = rwmb_meta( 'beschreibung_kategorie', array( 'object_type' => 'term' ), $term_id );
echo $value;
```

But anyway it is still not working.